# Locking records returned by context? Or perhaps a change to my approach

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm not sure whether I need a way to lock records returned by the context or simply need a new approach.

Here's the story. We currently have a small number of apps that integrate with our CRM. Some of them open a XrmServiceContext and return a few thousand record to perform updates. These scripts are calling SaveChanges along the way but there will still be accounts near the end that will be saved a couple of minutes after the context return them. If a user updates the record during this time, their changes are overwritten by the script.

Is there a way of locking the records until the context has saved the update back or is there a better approach I should be taking?

Kit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, this type of database transaction issue is what CRM is currently lacking the most.  There is no way to ensure that someone else doesn't monkey with your data, it's always a last-one-in-wins world in CRM.

With that being said, my suggestion would be to only update the attributes you care about.  If you're returning all columns for an entity, when you update that entity, you're possibly going to update all the attributes of the entity, even if you only updated one of them.

If you're dealing with a system were you can't tolerate the last-one-in-wins mentality, then you're probably better off not using CRM.

**Update 1**

CRM 2015 SP1 and above supports Optimistic Updates.  Which allows the use of a version number to ensure that no one has updated the record since you retrieved it.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. I'm marking this answer as correct as updating only the desired attributes will certainly limit the issue. I'm using the code from http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/crmdevelopment/thread/a6335a10-cdcd-4d6c-b533-068017df1dec to do small updates.

Answer (score 1):

You have a several options here, it just depends on what you want to do.  First of all though, if you can move some of these automated processes to off-time hours, then that's the best option.

Another option would be to retrieve each record 1 by 1 instead of by 1000+.

If you are only updating a percentage of the records retrieved, then you would be better off to check before saving if an update occurred (comparing the modified date).  If the modified date changed, then you need to do a single retrieve and then save.

Answer (score 0):

At first thought, I would create a field or status that indicates a pending operation and then use JScript in the form OnLoad event to warn/lock the form.  When you process completes, it could clear the flag.

Comment: This would have the same issue that I'm facing in that, to update the locking field for all the records, a similar period of time will pass as to what's required for the actual update.